# Fuse amperage for laptop PSU

Tags: laptop, acer-aspire, wiring

I have cord that is rather short, so I found a longer one and wanted to swap the IEC [kettle lead] type.
I checked the fuse to see if they are the same new one is a 5A & the existing one is 13A; can that be right for a laptop? It's an Acer A13-045N2A its the one that came  with the laptop (I don't remember changing the lead in the past but 13 sounds a bit high would it be safe to use the 5A).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain whether you mean the new lead is 5A or the existing...

5A is already a bit high for a computer PSU mains cable, but as that's the common minimum, it will be fine. If you were particularly paranoid a 3A would be 'safer' by the tiniest margin.

Most generic cables are supplied with 13A fuses, because that's just the maximum permissible load.

Swap the fuses over if you want, 10 second job, they pry out with a screwdriver on standard moulded plugs, or buy a pack from your local supermarket or DIY store. They cost pence.

I have assumed for this that we're talking UK plugs, as nowhere else seems to put fuses in them.

Comment: The existing that came with laptop is a 13 amp . The other is longer for an older laptop. Is a 5amp.

Comment: What are you trying to protect against? (In most countries, cables don't have fuses). That is not to say they are of no value, but the answer depends on what you are valuing.

Comment: @davidgo UK standard plugs, fuses are compulsory… plus the circuit won't work without one ;) Many Brits think the rest of the world has terrible mains rules, no fuse, no earth… Jay, the 5A is fine, just use the cable as it is, no need to swap.

Comment: @tetsujin I get that - but if its simply for compliance, a 13 amp fuse could be trivially better. If the goal is to protect the laptop at a risk of causing the fuse to blow, he will want the smallest fuse he can get (as long as its not less then 0.3 amps - as the laptop PSU is 65 watts). BTW, in NZ we don't need fuses, but we do have earth, and in any house with modern wiring multiple RCD's.  (Also, I put to you fuses offer cost++ for little gain when each circuit has a resetable fuse)

Comment: @davidgo - Standard fuses come in 3A, 5A & 13A. 13A is the total permissible load on any ring. RCDs are only compulsory in new builds, which means any property built before about 2008 won't necessarily have them - about 50% [govt data]. Fuses are compulsory in any mains extension cable, they're in the design - remove them you leave an open circuit. Generic ones have the legal max 13A, but the user can replace with one more appropriate to the use case. UK plugs are probably the most over-engineered, sockets too, you can't put anything in the socket until the earth pin has opened it.